# Embed Post not showing with FB.api Call Facebook Javascript Api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I'm using Facebook Javascript SDK and FB.api. I read public pages' posts and wanted to show it on my website. So I made the call with FB.api and got the response. But while I try to show them by [Facebook Embed System](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts) it just didn't show up.

Here is my code

```
FB.api("/" + PageId + "/posts",
    {
        access_token: getCookie("access_token"),
        since: From,
        until: To,
        fields: "id,likes.summary(true).limit(0),comments.summary(true).limit(0),shares,link",
        limit: LoadLimit,
        date_format: "U",
    },
    function (res) {
        $("#load_post").attr("disabled", false).attr("value", "Load Posts");
        if (typeof res.error === 'undefined') {
            if (res.data.length > 0) {
                for (var i = 1; i <= res.data.length; i++) {
                    var NewData = res.data[i - 1];
                    var Id = NewData.id.split("_")[1];
                    var CreatedTime = NewData.created_time;
                    var Likes = NewData.likes.summary.total_count;
                    var Comment = NewData.comments.summary.total_count;
                    var Share = 0;
                    var Link = NewData.link;
                    if (typeof NewData.shares !== 'undefined') {
                        Share = NewData.shares.count;
                    }
                    var Data = "";
                    Data += "<tr>";
                    Data += "<td>" + i + "</td>";
                    Data += "<td><div id='" + Id + "' class='fb-post' data-href='" + Link + "' data-width='350'></div></td>";
                    Data += "<td>" + CreatedTime + "</td>";
                    Data += "<td>" + Likes + "</td>";
                    Data += "<td>" + Comment + "</td>";
                    Data += "<td>" + Share + "</td>";
                    Data += "<td></td>";
                    Data += "<td></td>";
                    Data += "<td></td>";
                    Data += "</tr>";

                    $("#data_area").append(Data);
                    FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById(Id));

                }

            } else {
                alert("No data found.");
            }
        } else {
            alert("Error occured.\n" + res.error.message);
        }
    });
```

Even I tried "**FB.XFBML.parse**" but lately checking the documentation I found that it has no effect on Embed Post.

I checked the console and found no error or something.

Please help me out.

Comment: I would start debugging by trying this with a hardcoded post from https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-posts. Get the code from the story you're trying to post and just paste it there, see if that works.

Comment: Finally I've make it worked out. I used "<div id='my_id'><fb:post href='post_url'></fb:post></div>"
 and called the FB.XFBML.parse(document.getElementById('my_id'))
And it worked out.

Comment: for me it never worked... i moved on to embed.ly...